# Jest test fails when trying to test an asynchronous function throws

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs

I have an asynchronous function and I want to test for both: success and failure. On success the function returns a string, on failure it throws. I'm failing miserably at testing failure. Here's my code:

- getKmlFileName.test.js

I have disabled by commenting the code that fails and added the results in comments

```
    'use strict';

    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const getKmlFilename = require('./getKmlFileName.js');

    const createGoodFolder = () => {
      const folderPath = fs.mkdtempSync('/tmp/test-getKmlFilename-');
      const fileDescriptor = fs.openSync(path.join(folderPath, 'doc.kml'), 'w');
      fs.closeSync(fileDescriptor);
      return folderPath;
    };

    const createEmptyFolder = () => fs.mkdtempSync('/tmp/test-getKmlFilename-');

    describe('/app/lib/getKmlFilename', () => {
      // Success tests
      test('Should return a KML filename', async () => {
        const result = await getKmlFilename(createGoodFolder());
        expect(result).toMatch(/\.kml$/);
      });

      // Failure tests
      test('Should throw if no KML files in folder', () => {
        // Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.
        // expect.assertions(1);

        // expect(function).toThrow(undefined)
        // Received value must be a function, but instead "object" was found
        //return getKmlFilename(createEmptyFolder())
        // .catch(e => expect(e).toThrow());

        // expect(string)[.not].toMatch(expected)
        // string value must be a string.
        // Received:
        // object:
        // [Error: No valid KML file in /tmp/test-getKmlFilename-j2XxQ4]

        return getKmlFilename(createEmptyFolder())
          .catch(e => expect(e).toMatch('No valid KML file in'));
      });

      test('Should throw if no KML files in folder - try/catch version',
        async () => {
        // Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.
        // expect.assertions(1);

        try {
          const result = await getKmlFilename(createEmptyFolder());
        } catch (e) {
          // Received value must be a function, but instead "object" was found
          // expect(e).toThrow();

          // expect(string)[.not].toMatch(expected)
          // string value must be a string.
          // Received:
          // object:
          // [Error: No valid KML file in /tmp/test-getKmlFilename-3JOUAX]
          expect(e).toMatch('No valid KML file in');
        }
      });

    });
```

As you can see, nothing works. I believe my tests are almost an exact copy of [Promises](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#promises) example for the first failure test and [Async/Await](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#async-await) example for the last one, however none works.

I believe the difference with the examples from Jest documentation is that they show how to test a function `throw`s and how to test a Promise that `reject`s. But my promise rejects by throwing.

Checking the function in the node console I get this log:

```
// import function
> getKml = require('./getKmlFileName.js')
[AsyncFunction: getKmlFilename]
// trying it with a proper folder shows we get a Promise
> getKml('/tmp/con')
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
// trying it with a failing folder shows it's a rejected promise which throws
> getKml('/tmp/sin')
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> (node:10711) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No valid KML file in /tmp/sin
    at getKmlFilename (/home/flc/soft/learning/2018.06.08,jest/getKmlFileName.js:14:11)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
(node:10711) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10711) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

As you can see from the inlined comments, the function is doing what it should, however I don't know how to test this in Jest. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I case the code here looks too convoluted, I prepared a [repository](https://github.com/fernandocanizo/learning-jest) which contains my misfortunes learning Jest

**UPDATE 2018.06.12:**

Somehow my message got scrambled and lost the first part which was the actual code I'm trying to test, my apologies for that, here it is:

- getKmlFileName.js

  ```
  'use strict';
  const globby = require('globby');
  const path = require('path');

  const getKmlFilename = async (workDir) => {
    const pattern = path.join(workDir, '**/*.kml');
    const files = await globby(pattern);
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      // Return first KML found, if there are others (improbable), ignore them
      return path.basename(files[0]);
    } else {
      throw new Error(`No valid KML file in ${workDir}`);
    }
  };

  module.exports = getKmlFilename;
  ```

Comment: Are you always returning a Promise (is `getKmlFilename` declared async)?

Comment: @Narigo yes, as you can see in my update

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your first test:

```
return getKmlFilename(createEmptyFolder())
  .catch(e => expect(e).toMatch('No valid KML file in'));
```

It would not complain if the Promise resolves.

In the second test

```
try {
  const result = await getKmlFilename(createEmptyFolder());
} catch (e) {
  ...
}
```

It also would not complain if the Promise resolves as it would not get into the catch block.

To test Promises, ask yourself these questions:

1. Should the promise succeed (resolve) or fail (reject)?
2. Is your result or rejection value an `Error` or a regular object?

In jest, you should be able to do this:

1. Resolve to regular object: `expect(yourThing()).resolves.toMatchSnapshot()`
2. Resolve to error (never seen that):
   `expect(yourThing()).resolves.toThrow(/something/)`
3. Rejects to an error:
   `expect(yourThing()).rejects.toThrow(/something/)`
4. Rejects to a regular object (are you sure you want this?):
   `expect(yourThing()).rejects.toMatchSnapshot()`

Be aware that an async function always returns a value (a Promise object), so the "usual" `expect(() => yourThing()).toThrow()` will not work. You need to wait for the result of the Promise first (by using `resolves` or `rejects`) and then testing it.

Comment: The failing tests are the ones that test for failure, the succeding test works fine, is the first one. To answer your points: **1)** Both, first test tests success, the other two are two different ways I found in the docs to tests async code. **2)** Success result is a string, rejection result is an `Error` as you can see in my update. My doubt is: will Javascript `async` take care of wrapping the `throw` in a `reject` call? I thought it does. Finally, I'm trying to test for failure, so I don't expect promise to resolve successfully in my later tests. Why `expect.assertions(1)` doesn't work?

Comment: Finally got a chance to continue with this, the third way was what I needed to test a promise that throws. Thank you.

Comment: I guess all of us came for the 3rd way. Could you make that part of your excellent answer more pronounced?

Comment: It doesn't look like jest respects parameters here `rejects.toThrow(.....)`. No matter what I pass it accepts it and passes the test. Also if the promise resolves then `expect(myPromise()).rejects.toThrow()` will still pass the test but complain of `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expect(received).rejects.toThrow()
Received promise resolved instead of rejected`

Comment: Please change your 3rd example to `await expect(yourThing()).rejects.toThrow(/yourErrorMessage/)`

Comment: Would it be clear enough if I changed number 3 to `expect(yourThing()).rejects.toThrow(/your error message as regular expression match/)` ?

Comment: But _why_ do we need the `.resolves.` and `.rejects.` in there? Because the whole point of `await` is that it wraps a Promise such that it either yields data like any sync function, or throws an error.

Comment: If you `await` the promise and use `expect` on the result, that should work as you said - as the thrown error should be caught by the async context. If you're testing a rejected promise, you need the expectation in the catch block but you also need to make sure the promise doesn't accidentally resolve. I guess that's why `.rejects.` exists then